# Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Pro 2014 - 'iucode-tool 1.5.2-1' should I install it?

Tags: 16.04, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 2014 which runs an i7 processor.  Could someone please elaborate on what this package does (I understand it allows loading microcode into the processor but nothing else) and whether, or under what circumstances, it should be installed?

Answer (score 1):

iucode-tool should be installed together with the intel-microcode package.  It is (automatically) used by the intel-microcode package to update the initramfs.

intel-microcode has the microcode update data for hundreds of Intel processors, and iucode-tool is used to copy only the data that is needed by a specific processor into the initramfs so that the kernel can load it during early boot.

iucode-tool is also used to build the intel-microcode binary packages from several Intel data files included in the intel-microcode source package.

Normal users should always install the intel-microcode package to increase system stability.  This will also install the iucode-tool package as a dependency, since the intel-microcode package needs it.